# Is mailing from a fake address legal?

Tags: mail, postal-service

I know it is legal to send mail without a return address, but is it legal to mail with someone else's address? When I went to the post office the label machine did not have an option for "No Return Address". The problem is that I don't have a legal address to put down (and no I don't have friends or family to ask to borrow their address).

So how can I send mail without a legal address?

Comment: Could you use [General Delivery](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-is-General-Delivery) as the return address?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/is-it-ever-illegal-to-intentionally-put-a-wrong-return-address-on-demand-lette?rq=1

Comment: Couldn't you just address the letter by hand, instead of using the label machine?

Comment: Do you have a “staying address”?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert How do you pay for it?

Comment: At every post office I've been to, you can buy one or more postage stamps from the clerks at the service window and then ask them to mail it (or drop it in the appropriate slot in the lobby.)

Comment: Which country's postal service?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your legal question, but surely a good solution would be to use a pen to cross out the bad address? I'm sure someone would lend you a pen at the post office if you didn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean in the United States...

Mailing a letter does not always require a return address as you understand from your question.

A return address must appear legibly on:

- Mail of any class bearing a printed ancillary service request (i.e. "Return Service")
- Official mail
- Mail paid with precanceled stamps
- Matter bearing a company permit imprint
- Priority mail
- Periodicals in envelopes or opaque wrappers
- USPS retail ground
- Package services
- Parcel Select
- Registered Mail
- Insured Mail
- Collect on Delivery (COD) Mail
- Certified Mail (if a return receipt is requested)
- Priority Mail Express
- Detached Address Labels and detached marketing labels
- Adult signature required

Given that if your mail was not any of the above, you could make up an address *and then make it illegible* so that it cannot be read (using a pen or marker, or white-out to obscure the address). Do not keep a legible address that does not belong to you as the return address.

Comment: I’d think sending certified mail without return address for example isn’t illegal, but you won’t get any evidence that the mail was received.

Comment: @gnasher729 you can't give a letter to the postal service to be certified mail if you don't put on any return address - they don't accept it, and certified mail only forks from the counter.